# How to breakout the following code into individual classes in android

Tags: android, string, list, arrays

I have the following code that works and gives me the solution that I am looking for, however what I would like to do is break out the following section into i's own class so that I can initialize the array when the app starts:

```
            String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
    List<String> qlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s: questions){
        qlist.add(s);
    }
    questioncount = qlist.size();
    Collections.shuffle(qlist);
    int cr = (r.nextInt(questioncount - 0) + 0);
    ques.setText(qlist.get(cr).toString());
    Log.i("VertygoEclypse", qlist.get(cr).toString());
```

That being said the code is currently in the main OnCreate class of my main activity and what I would like is to break it out to it's own class. This will give me the ability to split the above code into 2 sections, one for the initialize part and another for a random selection part that will give me the ability to select questions at random and set it to a textview field in my app. My hope is to have the code as such:

```
    String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
    List<String> qlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s: questions){
        qlist.add(s);
    }
    questioncount = qlist.size();
    Collections.shuffle(qlist);
```

and the code that is not yet developed will be called public getquestion() will contain:

```
    int cr = (r.nextInt(questioncount - 0) + 0);
    ques.setText(qlist.get(cr).toString());
```

but instead of a counter it will be a random selection with a part to eliminate the selected item from the random array so that it is not selected the next time.

my goal is to have a quiz app that will pull a string-array from my strings file and upon a random selection set the textview as to those questions to give a score.
Below is the xml that I have develop so far:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    android:text="TextView" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rbg_answergroup"
    android:layout_width="188dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_dnm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Does Not Matter" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_att"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All the Time" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_st"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sometimes" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_naa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not at All" />
</RadioGroup>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousquestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_weight="33"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_weight="33"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextquestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="33" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current Total"
        android:paddingRight="25dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runningtotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />

</TableRow>
```

and following is the string.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

<string name="app_name">quiztest</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string-array name="questions">
   <item>Are you Drunk? </item>
   <item>Do you currently love everyone?</item>
   <item>Do you currently love your job?</item>
   <item>Do you prefer Beers over Rum?</item>
   <item>Do you currently wish to tell off your boss?</item>
   <item>Feel like taking a picture and sending it to someone?</item>
   <item>Spin around and when you stop are things spinning?</item>
   <item>Can you walk in a straight line?</item>
   <item>Does 1 + 1 = 11?</item>
   <item>Can you explain why "42" is the Secret to Life?</item>
   <item>How do you feel about checking out George Street for a Good Time?</item>
   <item>When you see a striped pants does your heart skip a beat?</item>
   <item>Can you say for sure that bad thoughts have not passed through your head about a co-worker?</item>
   <item>When is a good time to Drink?</item>
   <item>Can you only have 1 beer.</item>
   <item>Does the words 1-z mean just one beer?</item>
   <item>Can you say for sure that you have never instigated a Drinking lime?</item>
   <item>Given the opportunity to go home with a complete stranger will you?</item>
   <item>How much do you think that you can be a designated driver</item>
   <item>Given the chance to consumate with Sus scrofa domesticus will you?</item>
   <item>If real "HONGREE" will you eat dogfood?</item>
</string-array>
```

Any guidelines as to the above would be greatly appreciated I have attempted it but keep getting a null pointer issue when I move the above code to a separate class and try to return a string value only.

Below is the code that I currently have:

```
    package com.vertygoeclypse.quiztest;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView ques;
    TextView rt;
    Button nxtqstn;
    Button prvsqstn;
    Button sbtanswr;
    RadioGroup arg;
    int answertotal = 0;
    int rdochkid = -1;
    Random r = new Random();
    int questioncount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nxtqstn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextquestion);
    prvsqstn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousquestion);
    sbtanswr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbutton);
    arg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rbg_answergroup);
    ques = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.runningtotal);
    arg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            rdochkid = checkedId;
        }
    });
    prvsqstn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    nxtqstn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
    List<String> qlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s: questions){
        qlist.add(s);
    }
    questioncount = qlist.size();
    Collections.shuffle(qlist);
    int cr = (r.nextInt(questioncount - 0) + 0);
    ques.setText(qlist.get(cr).toString());
    Log.i("VertygoEclypse", qlist.get(cr).toString());
}
public void AnswerCheck(){
    if(rdochkid == -1){
        rdochkid = arg.getId();
    }
    if(rdochkid == R.id.rb_dnm){
        answertotal = answertotal+10;
    }
    if(rdochkid == R.id.rb_att){
        answertotal = answertotal+5;
    }
    if(rdochkid == R.id.rb_st){
        answertotal = answertotal+3;
    }
    if(rdochkid == R.id.rb_naa){
        answertotal = answertotal+1;
    }
}
public void resetquiz(){
    answertotal = 0;
    rdochkid = -1;
}
```

}

I believe that my issue is when I move this code:

```
    String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
    List<String> qlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s: questions){
        qlist.add(s);
    }
    questioncount = qlist.size();
    Collections.shuffle(qlist);
```

I am unable to return the qlist so that I can extract the string that my randomizer will choose.

Once more any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

regards

cchinchoy

Edit - 25/12/2013 - 8:30 p.m
Subsequent to the above, I have been trying to get the breakout going and I have gotten to this point.
I have the adapter code broken out and this is what it looks like:

```
    package com.vertygoeclypse.quiztest;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class QuizAdapter {
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
    String[] questions = null;
    List<String> qlist = null;
    private int questioncount;
    Random r = new Random();
    int cr;
    Context context;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

    QuizAdapter(Context context){
        Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 1");
        this.context = context;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
    void initializequestions(){
        Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 2");
        questions = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
        Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 3");
        qlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 4");
        for(String s: questions){
            Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 5");
            qlist.add(s);
    }
    questioncount = qlist.size();
    Collections.shuffle(qlist);
    cr = (r.nextInt(questioncount - 0) + 0);
    //      ques.setText(qlist.get(cr).toString());
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 20; counter++){
    Log.i("VertygoEclypse", qlist.get(counter).toString());
    }
}
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
public List<String> getquestions(List<String> qlist){
    return qlist;

}
    }
```

And in the Main Activity I put the code like this:

```
    Context context;
    QuizAdapter qa = new QuizAdapter(context);
```

and then:

```
            Log.i("VertygoEclypse", "Just before Null Pointer");
    qa.initializequestions();
    Log.i("VertygoEclypse", "Just after Null Pointer");
```

please also see below the logcat output, I am seeing that the system enters the method and bogs out with a null pointer at this point:

```
                Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 2");
        questions = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
        Log.i("QuizAdapter", "We Are Here - 3");
```

Please see the logcat output:

```
    12-26 00:24:46.247: I/QuizAdapter(1628): We Are Here - 1
    12-26 00:24:46.977: I/VertygoEclypse(1628): Just before Null Pointer
    12-26 00:24:46.977: I/QuizAdapter(1628): We Are Here - 2
    12-26 00:24:46.977: D/AndroidRuntime(1628): Shutting down VM
    12-26 00:24:46.977: W/dalvikvm(1628): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vertygoeclypse.quiztest/com.vertygoeclypse.quiztest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.vertygoeclypse.quiztest.QuizAdapter.initializequestions(QuizAdapter.java:28)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.vertygoeclypse.quiztest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    12-26 00:24:46.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

I think I am getting closer, but just need a little guidance on this, any help will be appreciated.

Regards

cchinchoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a quick example. Please excuse errors as I am typing in notepad ++ without SDK installed.

Something like the example below should work. Notice there are some issues such as:

- Can questions be reused?

The example below allows someone to not re-use questions in which case at some point all questions have been used and resetList() must be called. You can take a fixed version of the class below and input it into your android code.

Also, you can optimize to keep the original question list, and a copy so that you don't need to re-read the file in restList() method.

```
public class Questions
{

    private List<String> qlist;

    public Questions()
    {
        resetList()
    }

    public void resetList()
    {
        String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
        qlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s: questions){
            qlist.add(s);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(qlist);
    }

    public int getQuestionCount()
    {
        return qlist.size();
    }

    public String getRandomQuestion(boolean deleteIt)   //deleteIt means we do not show this again
    {
        if(qlist.size()==0) //No more questions
        return "No more questions";

        if(deleteIt)
        return qlist.removeElement(qlist.size()-1) //However method is called remove/pop/etc...

        return qlist.get(Math.Random()*(qlist.size()-0.1)).toString();  //or some other random generation
    }
}
```

Calling `getRandomQuestion(true)` deletes questions that are served. Using `false` instead means the same question can be served multiple times.

Fix errors as appropriate - hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, copied the class, had to clean up a couple of things. still getting the Null pointer error though, on the suggested call: `getRandomQuestion(true)`, I had to create a variable to link to the class, that is `Questions qa`; and then use it `ga.getRandomQuestion(true)`. that being said the line: `String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);` pushed an error on the getResources() method and I solved it by putting context before it. and of course at the top Context context.

Comment: The next issue I got was the `qlist.get` needed a casting of `(int)` for it to work. The line used to look like this: `return qlist.get(Math.Random()*(qlist.size()-0.1)).toString();`  and now looks like this: `return qlist.get((int) (Math.random()*(qlist.size()-0.1))).toString();`. Once more I appreciate your help. Also once the call returns, how do I get it to a string to SetText or is it that I set a string and make it equal to the call like this : `question = qa.getRandomQuestion(true);`. Thanks once more for the help.

Comment: Np. just woke up :). You do exactly that-  you assign the returned value to string called ef question. If you using the question only once you could also  do this: 'methodCalled(qa.getRandomQuestion(true))'

Comment: Still getting the null pointer. Being new to Android and eclipse, I wish here was a way to check for a null point on the variable within the `getRandomQuestion()` mwthod. That way I can see what is being returned in the log so that I can try and address it before it returns. If you have any ideas I am open to suggesstions. thanks.

Comment: Just also tried adding the code to the `resetlist()` prior to the call to `getRandomQuestion()` and it now puts the null pointer error on that line so it seems that the error pops once I call to any method within the Questions.java class. I am wondering if there is a way to set the questions variable so that it is not null within the function even if it does not perform the get of the string array.

Comment: was wondering, the `getResources()` works great if I call it within the `OnCreate` method of the main class, is there a way to pass 2 variables to the method for instance `question = qa.getRandomQuestion(context, true);` so the context of the main class is passed to the sub class but return only 1 variable. This might solve the problem.

Comment: Have you created a new question object? you could do System.out.println(qa==null) to print true if qa is null. Also if(whatever==null) canbe used to check any variable.

Comment: Hi, yes I created the question object: `String question = null;` but still no joy. I have also placed a call to set the context at `qa.setContext(this);` that links to `    public void setContext(Context context){Log.i("Questions", "Setting the context");this.context = context;}` in the hopes that the context can get set before any other items are called. This way the context for the activity is set and will give me the reference point to call the `getResources()`. however that still does not work. let me try the `System.out.println(qa==null)` and see what we get.

Comment: just tried the `System.out.println(qa==null);` and I got the print as true. So that means that qa is null, but that is strange if we can call the methods. Well for my limited knowledge I am even more stumped, but at least I know now that the qa being null seems to be the issue that we have to deal with.

Comment: ok, just did this `Questions qa = new Questions();` and the `System.out.println(qa==null);` no longer prints and I jump into the method. however we come back to the same issue as before where `questions = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);` forces a null pointer exception. Going to try the `System.out.println(qa==null);` on the context and see what that gives. will be right back.

Comment: ok, just tried it and my context comes back as true for null. So now I know that the issue is that my context is null. How do I get my context to hold its value through the process. I wonder if calling the setContext from the reset will help. will let you know the results.

Comment: can you tell me if this is correct: `    public void setContext(Context context){
     Log.i("Questions", "Setting the context"); 
     context = this.context;
    }
    public Context getContext(Context context){
     return context;
    }` the set context is being called from the main activity as `qa.setContext(this);` but the system out still prints for true on context.

Comment: Hey, I got it. yippeeeee!!!. Ok Let me explain how. firstly, we were on the right track for the setting of the context. this works:

Comment: That being said the call to the method is where the issue was happening.:`Questions.setContext(this);` what I ended up doing is to change the "this" to `getApplicationContext()` like this :`Questions.setContext(getApplicationContext());` and now it is working, now I am going to hard wire the `getRandomQuestion()` to a button so that it can be called numerous times and that is it. Thanks for all the help. You were very instrumental in getting me to the answer as well as to helping me to understand this concept.

Comment: I can't upvote till my reputation is over 15. So if you can do that for me to you that would be greatly appreciated.